# search a php string for two substrings

Tags: php, security, strpos

I am programming a php program that will allow users to download audio from my website.
 To do this they go to *www.mysite.com/downloadit.php?file=myfile.mp3*  and the download of *myfile.mp3* will begin immediately. 
There is a problem though: I don't want people to be able to download system files. I am going to solve this by checking if `$_GET['file']` contains the substrings `.mp3` or `.wav`. I am trying to do this with the `strpos` command, but can't get it working. How would I check for more than one substring (.mp3 and .wav) in a string with `strpos`? Or maybe I should use a different command? Please let me know!

Here is my code so far:

```
$haystack=$_GET['file'];

$resulting = strpos($haystack, ".mp3");

//if found $resulting will equal 1
//if not found $resulting will equal 0

//if $resulting is less than one then it must be 0

    if($resulting < 1){
    //security breach!
    die("Unauthorized");
}

//assuming we passed the last test, everything went well, we will then continue

    else{
    //code here
}
```

Thanks to @DoubleSharp i now have this completed code!!!

```
//if it is found $resulting will not equal 0
//if it is not found $resulting will equal 0

//echo the result
//echo $resulting;

//add a line break
echo "<br/>";
//if $resulting is less than one then it must be 0
//since it is 0 it must mean that it is a breach!
if (preg_match("~\.(mp3|wav)$~i", $haystack))
{
  echo "hi nice file";
}
else
{
  die("bad file");
}
?>
```

Comment: `substr_count()` and there you goooo. Though I have high doubts about the security ...

Comment: For better security, consider maintaining a list of files that may be downloaded and comparing the input to that list. At the very least, limit accessible files to a particular directory or set of directories.

Comment: People are uploading audio onto my website all the time, mantaing that list would require a whole new set of code. This way would be much easier. This is just a backup security system really.... I have one in front of this that makes sure they don't download outside of the /audio/ directory. Thx though

Comment: Put your downloadable files under a single directory.  When you get a filename from the client, check for the existence of the file in that directory only (filtering '.' and '..').  Otherwise, security is going to be an issue.  Make sure you don't allow for any kind of path in the filename....

Comment: so i should check for /'s too? good idea thanks!

Comment: @Shadowpat This isn't a great strategy ... You will have name collisions. Save the names into a DB, save the files in your folder with a unique hash as name.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV Why is this not a great strategy? Please explain

Comment: @Shadowpat Let me give you an example, let's say I upload `stackoverflow.mp3` and after a while someone else uploads `stackoverflow.mp3` how will you handle this ? (ps: they are different sounds)

Comment: Your syntax error is due to a missing `)` on the line with the `if` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to test for multiple values, specifically [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). If you use the pattern `\.(mp3|wav)$~i` wrapped in a delimiter (`~` in this case) it will match strings that end with a literal dot `.` followed by either `mp3` or `wav`. The `$` in the pattern matches the end of the line, and the `i` modifier at the end tells it to do case insensitive matching, so `file.MP3` and `file.mp3` will both match.

```
if ( preg_match("~\.(mp3|wav)$~i", $haystack) ) {
    // it matches
}
```

Comment: What is the difference with the ~'s and without?

Comment: @Shadowpat They're simply RegEx delimiters.  Use what you like, I tend to use `/`

Comment: @Shadowpat You can use any matching characters in place of the ```~```, it's just a delimiter. A forward slash is somewhat standard, but can get confusing when matching URLs since you have to escape them, which is why I opt for a tilde in these cases.

Comment: It also lets you add modifiers after your pattern - in this case ```i``` to make it case insensitive.

Comment: @doublesharp I keep getting an error (new code and error posted above)

Comment: Error found..... you had forgotten the last closing parenthesis. thx for the edit!

Comment: @doublesharp how do i do case insensitivity?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest something like:

```
$allowed = array('mp3', 'wav', 'ogg'); //whatever

$file = basename($_GET['file']);  // strip the path! (if any)

if(!preg_match("/\.(?:".implode('|', $allowed).")$/", $file){
   // Show 404, or whatever, exit
}

// Now check under trusted directories for the file,
// which should help to ensure that no system files are
// accessed since there shouldn't be any in there
```

Comment: @doublesharp has the better code, thank you though.. upvote! Also, I will use the idea for the allowed directories

Comment: Thanks - I prefer having things like allowed file types kept separately from (for example) a RegEx which checks for them, hence the dynamic RegEx here.  Also thought the `basename` idea was a good one.

Comment: This is a better solution since it's stripping the path **+1**